# Why do neural networks have bias units?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, bias

Why do neural networks have bias units? Why is it sometimes okay to opt them out?

Comment: Hey, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/role-of-bias-in-neural-networks), it explains it quite well.